# SmtpClient.Send causes memory leak

Tags: .net, smtp

I have a memory leak when calling `SmtpClient.Send()`.

I have a service for sending emails. I noticed a memory leak in TaskManager. I commented out the `SmtpClient.Send()` line, and when I started the service again, I noticed that the memory usage didn't increase.

Comment: Well great... Can you post some more details? How did you find out that there is a memory leak in Send()? Can you post the output of the tool that you used?

Comment: I have service for sending mails. The memory leak I noticed by TaskManager. I commented SMTPClient.Send() row, and when I started service again I noticed that the memory doesn't grow up.

Answer (score 3):

It is a very common mistake to assume that Taskmgr.exe is a leak detection tool.  The combination of the .NET garbage collector and the Windows heap manager is far too sophisticated to be reverse-engineered from the numbers you see in that tool.

Proof it to yourself by sending thousands of email messages.  If SmtpClient.Send() really leaks then your program will quickly crash with a OutOfMemory exception.  Get more insight in the memory usage of a .NET program with Perfmon.exe and the performance counters in the .NET CLR Memory category.  And a good book, like Richter's CLR via C#.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I checked the memory with other tools too, and the result is the same.

Comment: We can't look over your shoulder.  I don't think anybody can help you until you document what you found with those "other tools".

Comment: I am sending 1500 mails at once and my memory grow up like 30 Mb

Comment: You've got about ~1800 MB to go before you have a real problem.  Keep sending, try a million.