# Memory leak is seen when SmtpClient send function called multiple times

Tags: c#

[image: .net memory profiler report]I have to send mails multiple times, when this is done multiple times by using smtpclient class, Memory is increasing drastically......

I have tried with following things...
- Calling dispose methods for MailMessage, smtpclient
- calling GC.collect method manually
Nothing helped me...

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            using (var smtpobj = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"))
            {
                mail.To.Add("xxx@gmail.com");
                mail.From = new MailAddress("yyy@gmail.com");
                mail.Subject = "subject - .net app";
                mail.Body = "body";
                smtpobj.Port = 587;
                smtpobj.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yyy@gmail.com", "xyz");
                smtpobj.EnableSsl = true;
                smtpobj.Send(mail);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string strReturn = ex.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(strReturn);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You don't dispose `MailMessage`, but you should, because it implements `IDisposable`. Although you don't add any views, so I don't think this is the actual solution to your problem.

Comment: How are you determining that you have a memory leak?

Comment: I observe huge memory is getting piled up in task manager, plus once memory goes up never comes down...

Comment: [It is a very common mistake to assume that Taskmgr.exe is a leak detection tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2116406/47589)

Comment: You're better using the profiling tools inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SmtpClient.Send causes memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115677/smtpclient-send-causes-memory-leak)

Comment: If you say Task manager is not the best way to check the memory leaks... Then what will happen when Memory will reach the threshold value in task manager,According to me this will crash my application at that point. Because everyday after sending few hundred mails memory increases by approx 20 MB.

Comment: .... Use a tool designed to detect memory leaks.  You are making some faulty assumptions based on the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @Amy I have done analysis using .net memory profiler tool. I have attached a snapshot here.. it shows that 2000 smtpclient object has been disposed but not garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            using (var smtpobj = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"))
            {
                mail.To.Add("xxx@gmail.com");
                mail.From = new MailAddress("yyy@gmail.com");
                mail.Subject = "subject - .net app";
                mail.Body = "body";
                smtpobj.Port = 587;
                smtpobj.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yyy@gmail.com", "xyz");
                smtpobj.EnableSsl = true;
                smtpobj.Send(mail);
                smtpobj.ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup( 
                        smtpobj.ServicePoint.ConnectionName);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string strReturn = ex.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(strReturn);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This is per: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/28b59c25-bc93-4285-860d-52f1f49d2d43/net-smtp-class-memory-leakage?forum=netfxbcl